# After a GAN is trained, which parts of it are used to generate new outputs from data?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

After a GAN is trained, which parts of it are used to generate new outputs from data?

A) Neither
B) Discriminator
C) Generator
D) Both B and C

Answer (score 1):

The Discriminator is responsible to distinguish between the real image and the fake image and the generator is responsible to generate the fake images. This [link](https://pathmind.com/wiki/generative-adversarial-network-gan) provides a good guide for the generative adversarial networks.

Therefore, after training is done, you can just keep the generator to generate new outputs.